# Arduino doesn't get recognized

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm not certain this is the right place to ask, but I've seen other Arduino threads on stackoverflow, so I just assume it's ok.

My arduino uno-compatible board is not getting recognized. I tried it on windows 8 and on windows xp. When I open the device managers, there is just one entry called 'USB serial port' under the 'Ports (COM & LPT)' section. The Arduino, however, does blink when connected.

I tried uninstalling the usb serial port drivers, or updating them, but both don't work: the drivers seem to be up to date and when I uninstall and reconnect the arduino, they appear again.

When I try to upload a program I get

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00
```

or

```
avrdude: usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb"
```

(when I use 'upload using programmer').

I hope anyone can help me with this, I've been trying to get it to work now for quite some time.

[image: Screenshot of my device manager, with the Arduino Uno-compatible board connected and blinking]

EDIT 2: I tried the same thing at my parents' computer, which has windows vista installed. There, the board gets recognized as a USB serial port under 'Unknown devices' (first as something else, I think it was a code with two uppercase letters and then four digits, but I'm not sure and I can't get that name back, even after uninstalling the drivers).

Comment: The Arduino blinks because it's got power - there's a little sketch called "blink" pre-installed... Do you use a powered hub for your connection?

Comment: Are you connecting it via a USB 3.0 port ? Drivers don't support it yet.

Comment: If your board is Uno compatible and you have the drivers installed you should be able to get this to work by selecting the correct board (Uno) under Tools | Board and serial port (try all COM ports listed) under Tools | Serial Port. With these selected, upload using File | Upload. Also look at the troubleshooting guide here: http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/troubleshooting#toc1

Comment: @Floris: I know the blink sketch :) I think the usb hub is bus-powered, could that be a problem?

Comment: @AshRj: I think the USB ports are 2.0, can't really find it in the device manager...

Comment: Try connecting directly to the PC without a hub?

Comment: @Floris How would that work?

Comment: It can be a broken cable, too. I had this issue that the official Arduino cable did not work, but my Samsung mobile loading cable worked properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately got it working using the [Arduino Enchanched Release for Windows](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-erw/). That installed the right drivers for me. Then I had to choose the Duemilanov board (while the actual board is a 'Uno'). I think I tried that board before, but apperently I didn't have the right drivers installed at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the drivers? See the Arduino [installation instructions](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/Windows) under #4.
If you are trying with Windows 8 there are [some other steps involved](http://www.bryonconnolly.com/windows-8-arduino-driver-install).

Comment: Tried that, but my Arduino still isn't there in the device manager...
Too bad, seemed like it could work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Arduino UNO instructional video that shows how to install the drivers. The following url should start you at the part where the instructor talks about manually installing the driver.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=kLd_JyvKV4Y&t=1140

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter the following error "USB Arduino not recognized" on Windows 10 and 11 here's what you need to do:

1. open a new blank sketch on Arduino IDE.
2. Put the board into programable mode, by clicking 2 times consecutively on the reset button. A amber LED light up.
3. Open preferences and on "show verbose output" disable "on compilation" and "upload". Close preferences.
4. Upload the blank sketch into the board.
5. Copy & paste your code into the new blank sketch

If the same error appears again, it means you have an error in your code. For instance missing a return statement on a method inside a class, like the example below:

```
//***********************************************************************
class MString {
  public:
    MString() {
    }

    String replaceChr(String str, String oldChar, String newChar) {
      if (newChar == "\0") {
        // remove occurences of newChar in str
        while (str.indexOf(oldChar) > -1) {
          int pos = str.indexOf(oldChar);
          str.remove(pos, 1);
        }
      } else {
        str.replace(oldChar, newChar);
      }
      // !!!!
    }
};

MString mString = MString();
```

on this case, code validation was not throwing any error on Arduino IDE 1.8.15, and upload was successful. To fix it i simply added the return statement of the method: `return str;`

The USB error is gone!!! and fully working again.