# Arduino Industrial 101 does not get recognized

Tags: arduino, ide

After I searched for this issue and did not find a solution yet, I will ask here:

I have a Windows 10 computer with Arduino IDE 1.8.5 installed.
When I try to connect my Arduino Industrial 101, it is not possible to select the COM port in the IDE. Additionally, it isn't even shown in the device manager as "unknown device" as e.g. [Arduino COM port doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224360/arduino-com-port-doesnt-work) or [Arduino doesn't get recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993061/arduino-doesnt-get-recognized) state.

Before anyone asks:
-I ran the installer as administrator

-The device drivers are installed (At least they were ticked in the installer programm)

-I have this issue on a second computer (Windows 7 with Arduino IDE 1.8.5), too

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

EDIT: I tried again with the NodeMCU: The IDE shows COM port 7 in the information area on the lower right but when uploading I get a "Failed to open COM7" error. So, it seems to be a general IDE issue...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue... You won't believe me but either it was a broken cable or a cable that does not have enough power supply somehow. Strangely, this was the official cable from the Arduino package I got. My Samsung mobile cable saved the day^^